# Django: Form Handling Errors. Processing a Form associated with another Model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to be able to submit reviews for teachers. I have 2 models:

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')

class Review(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    #other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        #Note no 'teacher' in fields below
        fields = ('title','star','body')
```

**views.py** I have the following form handling:

```
def teacher_view(request,**kwargs):
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    #if request.method == 'POST':
    #handle the form
    review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
    review_form.teacher=teacher
    if review_form.is_valid():
         review_form.save()
         return redirect('users:index')
    else:
```

For some reason, I also seem to get the else loop. E.g. the form is not valid.

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.teacher_view, name='detail')
```

---

**Full Views.py**

```
def teacher_profile(request, **kwargs):
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=kwargs['pk'])
    star = Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=kwargs['pk']).aggregate(Avg('star'))
    no_of_ratings = Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=kwargs['pk']).count()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'booking' in request.POST:
            form = BookingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #handle the form
                return redirect('users:index')
            else:
                review_form = ReviewForm()
        elif 'review' in request.POST:
            review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            review_form['teacher']=teacher
            if review_form.is_valid():
                review_form.save()
                return redirect('users:index')
            else:
                form = BookingForm()
        else:
            form = BookingForm()
            review_form = ReviewForm()
    else:
        form = BookingForm()
        review_form = ReviewForm()

    return render(request, "users/teacher_detail.html", context={"form": form,
                                                                 "review_form":review_form,
                                                                 "teacher":teacher,
                                                                 "reviews":reviews,
                                                                 "star":star,
                                                                 "no_of_ratings":no_of_ratings,
                                                                 })
```

I've added the code again. I've copy pasted it from my views.py, but removed the form handling where I just define variables and redirect to another page with a success message.

I think why the logic in your answer is wrong, because it first checks if form is valid, which is not valid because teacher is missing. And then we define the teacher, after checking if it was valid. I tried manipulating the code by adding `review_form['teacher']=teacher` before `form.is_valid()`, but always get the error:

> 'ReviewForm' object does not support item assignment

Comment: in your `ReviewForm` you use `model = Review` but in the initial data you provide the instance of the `Teacher` model

Comment: Do you mean the instance=teacher part? Even if it's not there, I still get invalid form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to add teacher if ReviewForm is valid:

```
def teacher_profile(request,**kwargs):
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    reviews = teacher.review_set.all()
    star = reviews.aggregate(Avg('star'))
    no_of_ratings = reviews.count()

    form = BookingForm()
    review_form = ReviewForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'booking' in request.POST:
            form = BookingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #Correct handling
                return redirect('users:index')
        elif 'review' in request.POST:
            review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if review_form.is_valid():
                review = review_form.save(commit=False)
                review.teacher = teacher
                review.save()
                return redirect('users:index')
    context = {
       "form":form,
       "review_form":review_form,
       "teacher":teacher,
       "reviews":reviews,
       "star":star,
       "no_of_ratings":no_of_ratings,})
    return render(request, "users/teacher_detail.html", context)
```

in the `teacher_detail.html` add,

```
{{ review_form.errors }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't redirect or create a review. I posted the full content of my view function

Comment: try to look on your form errors in the console by add print after `else`

Comment: When I tried doing that, the function print is highlighted in grey, and is no errors are printed when I submit the form.

Comment: after putting {{ review_form.errors }} in my template, I get the error: teacher
This field is required. So I'm assuming teacher is not assigned to the form properly

Comment: you show wrong (not working) code in your full view.

Comment: I did not add print, because errors were not printed. Can you suggest where is it incorrect?

Comment: your code has syntax error, so i think you modified your real code with errors, if you need help you need show your real code.

Comment: I added my views.py file (copy and pasted it), and also a comment. I think form is not valid, because teacher should be assigned before checking the form

Comment: you can try new version, if in your form code valid it does not check `teacher` on `is_valid`.

Comment: I get the error: teacher: This field is required. To solve this, I added blank=true. Then it works. But I'd prefer if the field was required. Do you know how I could work around it?

Comment: i try your code and don't have the errors, it looks like you have some else code that generate the error

Comment: I will look into it and play around with the code, spasibo))

Comment: hope it help you)